# Fabric.js - Rotate change the position of object

Tags: rotation, position, fabricjs

I would rotate an object on FabricJS canvas, but when I rotate, its position changed. And I can't use center origin, just left/top, beacuse I save coordinates to database reference by left/top position.

Can you help me? Any idea?

Here is the example.

Thanks

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    angle: 0,
    fill: '#00AC6B'
}));

function rotateObject(angleOffset) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if (!obj) return;

    var angle = obj.getAngle() + angleOffset;

    angle = angle > 360 ? 90 : angle < 0 ? 270 : angle;

    obj.setAngle(angle).setCoords();

    canvas.renderAll();
    
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += 'Left: ' + obj.left + ', top: ' + obj.top + '<br>';
}

fabric.util.addListener(document.getElementById('rotate-left'), 'click', function () {
    rotateObject(-90);
});
fabric.util.addListener(document.getElementById('rotate-right'), 'click', function () {
    rotateObject(90);
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.log {
  height: 220px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/1.x/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div>
    <button id="rotate-left">Rotate left</button>
    <button id="rotate-right">Rotate right</button>
</div>
<div id="log" class="log">

</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want to rotate your object and save coordinates?

Comment: Yes, but whitout center origin, the left/top coordinates are changed when I rotate.

Comment: Just store an angle and apply it every time when you are getting data

Comment: But I need save position too, beacuse the object is draggeble.

Comment: I your post you specified you are saving your coordinates. Can you describe better what is the issue and what is expected result?

Comment: That is the position that fabric rendering is using to get you the rotated object in that position. The rotation is center based, so the top left corner has to change position.